# Blocking certain devices and browsers from my website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, browser

What is the best method to block (give them a message to know what browsers the site is compatible for) old versions of browsers and mobile devices from my website?

Comment: what server technology are you using?  @Tom Zych: I usually do something to prevent IE7 and below from trying to render my pages... easier to not support nonstandard browsers than to try to accommodate them.

Comment: well since jquery does not support IE5- it is good to be sure that no-one gets scared of the errors they don't understand and they need to be informed how they can do it better...

Comment: well i rent a server somewhere so i don't know anything about any stats and stuff alike... :(

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to use feature detection to detect whether the features you require are supported by the browser.  The library [modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) contains a wealth of feature detection logic that you can either use from the library or you can borrow individual elements from and copy into your code.  The reason this is the best way is because you aren't stuck with tracking and keeping up with individual versions of individual browsers and you aren't relying on browser type and version identification which is not guaranteed to be accurate and can be explicitly set by users to spoof.  With feature detection, either the host browser has a capability you need or it doesn't and this is figured out at run-time.  If your site is not usable on small screens, you can use feature detection to test for window size.

Another way (but certainly not the best way) is to detect a browser type and version and inform the user if they are using a version you haven't tested.  You can use the `navigator.userAgent` property and examine what's in that string to identify various browsers and browser versions.  There's a whole library [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html) that gives you an idea what you can look for.

If you're using jQuery, then you can use [`jQuery.browser`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) and `jQuery.browser.version` as it has already parsed some of the information from the useragent string.

Comment: +1 for modernizr and feature detection. It's a good library I see a lot of people using.

Answer (score 0):

Anything can be "spoofed" but you could use jquery.browser to do this. Find more info here: [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/)

A few conditional if else if statements could provide an error message that their browser is not compatible.  Again this would not be 100% fool proof, but if you are trying to block users that are still using really old browsers, I would think it would be pretty effective.